# Is it possible to create __attribute__((__constructor__)) functions in Cython source?

Tags: python, c, gcc, cython

When writing a Cython implementation file (.pyx), is it possible to define functions that are the [`__attribute__((__constructor__))` or `__attribute__((__destructor__))`](http://phoxis.org/2011/04/27/c-language-constructors-and-destructors-with-gcc/) of the shared library that Cython will create as the extension module?

It wouldn't make sense to place these as prototype declarations in a header file unless you also then defined them in a C file and compiled it such that the function implementations could be `cimport`ed... but then the `__constructor__`-ness of the function would apply to *that* compiled library, *not* to the one compiled by Cython.

Note that I am *not* referring to `__cinit__` or `__dealloc__` for extension *types* but instead to C-specific functions that are designed to run upon library load or unload.

It is not clear to me if the requirements of a module built with the CPython API (e.g. `Py_InitModule`) prevent the module from having any other function built as an entry hook that is automatically invoked when the library is loaded (or unloaded as for the destructor).

Comment: Probably not. Why, may I ask?